# Angularjs child scope not being picked up by Controller

Tags: angularjs

I am writing down a simple application and for some reason, I don't have access to my variable in the controller.

Here are the snippets of code

In controller (say parentTmp.js)

```
function parentController($scope) {
    $scope.tmp = {foo: 'abc'};
    ....
    function getTmpValue() {
        console.log("$scope.tmp.foo " + $scope.tmp.foo);
    }
}
```

In my view (parentTmp.html)

```
<div>
  <div ng-include="'childTmp.html'"></div>
  ...
<div>
```

In childTmp.html

```
<div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="tmp.foo" />
  <button ...>
</div>
```

On the interface, I enter a different value of say "Hello Stackoverflow" :-). However, when I click on button and call getTmpValue() function, I still get "abc" in the console.

It works perfectly ok if I have my input text box in parentTmp.html but as soon as I put that in the embedded html, it doesn't work.

It would be great if someone please point me in right direction. Thanks

Comment: How do you call `getTmpValue()`?

Comment: Actually this is a part of main form. When main form is submitted I call this

    <button ng-click="getTmpValue()" />